# How To Find Cookie Header Thing

Tags: python, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, tiktok

So I'm working on this thing and it asks for me to:

1. Sign into TikTok in your browser by choice (I'm using chrome)
2. Open DevTools and go to the network tab
3. Reload the page and find the sent cookie header
4. Copy the header
   Also, it says to do the same for Reddit so please tell me how to do that too (unless it's the same thing)
   Just so you know they are not trying to steal my account and if they do it's just a fake account but I want to know how to do this. Even a video tutorial would be amazing.

Comment: What issue are you running into when trying to copy the header?

Comment: Despite your assurances that they aren't trying to steal your account, I'd be very cautious. If they have the sent-cookie header, they can log into your account.

Comment: Could you explain why you're doing this? If you give an explanation as to why you're not being scammed, deceived or manipulated out of your account, I'll be happy to help.